# Connection to the database will execute only if the username is same with the database had

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I got a problem here with Log on the User. Whenever I run the program, the program will not execute the `Wait` form, unless the `Username` is same with the database had.

I want to whenever the user enter the different `Username` with the database, the `Wait` form will execute too, not only when the `Username` is same with the database had.

Here is the code:

```
private void CheckUserDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [Member] WHERE [Username] = @Username";

        conn.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

            using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dReader.Read())
                {
                    _wait.ShowDialog();

                    UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUserLanguage = comboBox1.Text;
                    UserInformation.Password = (string)dReader["Password"];

                    isValidPassword = BCrypt.CheckPassword(this.textBox2.Text, UserInformation.Password);

                    if (isValidPassword)
                    {
                        System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                        sound.Play();

                        DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Verified", "Congratulations", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                        if (_dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInName = (string)dReader["ChosenName"];
                            UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser = (string)dReader["Username"];
                            UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUserType = (string)dReader["UserType"];
                            UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUserStore = (string)dReader["UserStore"];

                            this.Hide();

                            Choices _choices = new Choices();
                            _choices.ShowDialog();

                            this.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!isValidPassword)
                    {
                        System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                        sound.Play();

                        DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Not Verified", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                        if (_dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            Validation(sender, e);

                            RecursiveClearTextBoxes(this.Controls);
                        }
                    }
                }

                dReader.Close();
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckUserDatabase(sender, e);
}
```

Here is the image:

[image]

**Info: `this.textBox2.Text` is the `Password` Text Box, and `this.textBox1.Text` is the `Username` Text Box, and `button1_Click` is the `Log on` button.**

***Note: the `_wait.ShowDialog` is the `Wait` form like the image below:***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckUserDatabase(sender, e);
}
```

To this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _wait.ShowDialog();
    CheckUserDatabase(sender, e);
}
```

and remove `_wait.ShowDialog();` from the `CheckUserDatabase()` method.